# gitlab] how the disable the user confirmation e-mail

Tags: email, gitlab, confirmation

Currently, I am using Gitlab, and I love using this great one.

However, some users cannot receive the confirmation email and cannot loggin.
I would like to 1) confirm them through my admin privilege or 2) configure the system not to send the email confirmation.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure as I cannot try it, yet: Did you try setting `signup_enabled: false`, temporarily? So you should be able to create gitlab users via admin access.

Answer (score 6):

Like @shin-haeng-kang said, for a new user, setting `signup_enabled: false` in the site settings and creating users from the admin menu and then editing the password after creating the user will work.

If the users already exists, I found the following [issue request](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6888) that shows how to edit the postgres database manually.

From the gitlab server:

```
sudo -u git -H psql -d gitlabhq_production
gitlabhq_production=> update users set confirmation_token=null, confirmed_at=now() where confirmed_at is null;
```

Comment: Better keep in mind that if you have a default installation, Gitlab will use an bundled Postgresql instance. You may connect to this one with: "sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql -d gitlabhq_production" as explained at Gitlab docs: http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html.